# Use state change without re-running useEffect/useMemo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with some state, and I want to use said state in a callback. This is one way to do it:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    // Imagine many states
    const [state, setState] = useState(0)

    const ref = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        function onPointerDown(event) {
            console.log(state)
        }
        ref.current.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown)
        return () => ref.current.removeEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown)
    }, [state])

    return <button ref={ref}>{props.title}</button>
}
```

This works, but the effect runs (and attaches & deattaches the listener) every time the state changes, which is not needed. Instead, if we could access the current state in `onPointerDown`, the effect would never have to re-run at all:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(0)
    const realState = useRef() // this will always return the same object
    realState.state = state

    const ref = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        function onPointerDown(event) {
            console.log(realState.state)
        }
        ref.current.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown)
        return () => ref.current.removeEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown)
    }, [])

    return <button ref={ref}>{props.title}</button>
}
```

This way, whenever the state changes, the callbacks created inside useEffect have access to the current state without the entire onEffect having to run again.

In my real use case, the useEffect is quite large, and has its own dependencies, but it depends on data that potentially changes every frame, so running the effect every time is costly. My question is: am I doing this right? Is there a better way to achieve this result?

Comment: Interesting ... I actually don't see a problem with that, technically, apart from that it's unusual (i.e. harder to read). Of course this specific example could be done differently, e.g. with the `onPointerDown` property, but let's assume there are reasons. Maybe the question is, if the `useEffect` really needs to be that large ? I'd try to split it into less complex custom hooks.

Comment: @kca Well, it's not incredibly large, but it attaches many listeners to different elements, including the document itself (pointer up, move, down, key to multiple elements). Some elements can be dragged by the user, updating the state of the main component (which includes the positions of all elements) basically on every frame. So running the effect every time is really unnecessary, but the callbacks need to access the state (element positions, what elements are selected etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody has posted an answer, I've decided to share what I ultimately went with. Basically, what I posted in the original question, but in the form of a neat little hook, which is only 1 line of code, but simplifies type-checking (if you use TypeScript) quite a lot:

```
export function useCallbackState<T>(state: T): T {
    return Object.assign(useRef(), state)
}
```

This always returns the same object, but on every call (render) new property values are set on said object, so existing callbacks that depend on it can use the new values, for example:

```
// These states will be updated and the component re-rendered
const [text, setText] = useState<string | null>(null)
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
// Use callback state
const s = useCallbackState({count, text})

// Attach the listener on-mount
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
useEffect(() => {
    function onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        // This will always print "0, null", unless we change the dependency array to [text, count],
        // which re-runs the effect every time - we don't want that!
        console.log(`old state variables: ${count}, ${text}`)
        // The 's' object is always the same - if the component re-renders, its 'count' and 'text'
        // properties are changed, but because s is the same, we can access the new values like so:
        console.log(`current state: ${s.count}, ${s.text}`)
    }

    ref.current.addEventListener("click", onClick)
    return () => ref.current.removeEventListener("click", onClick)
}, []) // or '[s]' to calm ESLint down - it will still only run just once

// This also works with useCallback:
const callback = useCallback(() => {
    // can use 's.text' and 's.count' here freely
}, [])
// So that memoized components that receive 'callback' as a prop don't have to re-render
```

Of course, the only thing you have to be careful about is - only use it for callbacks such as event listeners, never depend on it if you want your component to re-render! For example, using it inside an `onEffect` will cause that effect to never run again, even if the props change. It should only be used for external triggers (such as mouse/keyboard/resize events).

Comment: `Object.assign( useRef(), state )` (which expands to `Object.assign( useRef(), {count, text} )`) should not work (because: `Reflect.isExtensible( useRef() ) === false`). Does it really work for you, or is that a mistake ?

Comment: Is that really so? I'm running React 18, and `Reflect.isExtensible(useRef())` returns `true` for me. Besides, nowhere in the docs does it say that it's not extensible. Only that it returns the same object every time, and that only the `current` property is ever set by React (as initial value or if passed as the `ref` prop). Maybe you're referring to the ref returned by forwardRef, which is actually a function?

Comment: I guess, if there's ever an issue, you can always replace it with `return Object.assign(useRef({}).current, state)`

Comment: I confirm `isExtensible` returns `true` in React 18. Interesting again. The docs only mention the `.current` property, so I'd only use documented features, because React may change anything else at any time. But I agree, I can't think of a problem with using `ref` directly (apart from possible React internals which I don't know).